# Converting integers to string to a text file

Tags: python

I am writing a card game and writing it to a text file. These are my instructions...."When you write output into the text file, you can’t directly write the numeric variable
into the text file. The numeric variable needs to be converted into string before
writing into the text file."

[image]

I need to covert these integers into a string. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Please paste your code instead of a screen of it. It makes it easier to search through.

Comment: So where would i place the str(n) function in this print line:                      
  print (player + " have " + hand[0] + " and " + hand[1])

Answer (score 2):

To convert number to string in Python, just use `str(n)`, where `n` is number.

Comment: So where would I place the str(n) function in this print line? : print (player + " have " + hand[0] + " and " + hand[1])

Comment: Around int values to print, that is  str(hand[0]) and str(hand[1])